Conditional on module resource
I'm using a Terraform module and want to make one of the keys under it conditional.
module "cloudfront" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/cloudfront/aws"
  version = "~>3.2"

  ordered_cache_behavior = [{
    count                     = each.value.main_website ? 1 : 0 # ISSUE IS HERE
    use_forwarded_values      = false
    target_origin_id          = "s3_one"
  ]}
}

I want to add the ordered_cache_behavior only when the each.value.main_website is TRUE.
Currently it's being added even if the value is false.

That module doesn't have a for_each so I'm not sure where each.value is coming from. Either that code throws an error, or it isn't your actual code.

@MarkB This is a simplified version of my code.

In order for the count to take effect, it needs to be outside of the resource definition. The following worked:
module "cloudfront" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/cloudfront/aws"
  version = "~>3.2"

  ordered_cache_behavior = ! each.value.main_website ? [] : [{
    use_forwarded_values      = false
    target_origin_id          = "s3_one"
  ]}
}

This way if specifies that when the value for each.value.main_website is false, it should return the empty array [], and when the value is true it should return the array with the entry in it.
